# Android scale image view with animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

i have an `ImageView` and would like to scale it smaller with animation.
i use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.7"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.7"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="10%"
        android:duration="1500" />
</set>
```

This works good. But after the animation is finished the image gets back to its original size. Any ideas why?

Comment: "the original size of my image will set", **how set?**

Comment: this is the question. iin my xml layout file i set the width and height of the image (200dp). this size will be show at start - than start the animation and than the original size again

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-animations-explained.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution. is this correct like this? or it is quick and dirty? ^^

```
    ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "scaleX", 0.7f);
    ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "scaleY", 0.7f);
    scaleDownX.setDuration(1500);
    scaleDownY.setDuration(1500);

    ObjectAnimator moveUpY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "translationY", -100);
    moveUpY.setDuration(1500);

    AnimatorSet scaleDown = new AnimatorSet();
    AnimatorSet moveUp = new AnimatorSet();

    scaleDown.play(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY);
    moveUp.play(moveUpY);

    scaleDown.start();
    moveUp.start();
```

Answer (score 6):

Try with this code, it will not reset the image size after animation, here view is the imageview you want to animate.

```
ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 0.5f);
ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 0.5f);
scaleDownX.setDuration(1000);
scaleDownY.setDuration(1000);

AnimatorSet scaleDown = new AnimatorSet();
scaleDown.play(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY);

scaleDown.start();
```

Comment: NEW QUESTION: How looks the code, if i would to scale down AND move position up?

Comment: means, can you explain?

Comment: something like this: 
Animation slideUp = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -100);
slideUp.setDuration(1500);

Comment: ObjectAnimator slideUp = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", 0, -100);

Answer (score 4):

A simplier answer is below;

```
imageview.animate().translationY(-200F).duration = 500
imageview.animate().scaleY(0.4F).duration = 500
imageview.animate().scaleX(0.4F).duration = 500
```